# Set object origin for all frames in the animation

Tags: animation, constraints, origin

I have a mesh sequence imported into Blender using [Stop Motion OBJ](https://github.com/neverhood311/Stop-motion-OBJ). I also inserted a Bezier circle to the scene which I set as the target of a Follow Path constraint attached to an Empty (cube), which is the parent of my camera that has a Track To constraint to the object (mesh sequence) so that I can keyframe the Offset parameter and move the camera along the Bezier circle in my animation. See the scene in the attached image.

However, as you see in the image the object origin is by default at the bottom of the object, so the camera looks at the feet of the object. I want rather the camera to look at the center of the object during the whole animation. Now I can set this for one frame using *Object > Set Origin > Origin to Center of Mass (Volume)* but I can't figure out how to do this for all the other animation frames. How can I apply the desired object origin setting to the whole animation?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a different object every single frame or is it just one object but the mesh changes each frame?

Comment: Also, can you share the blend file?

Comment: It is a moving human model i.e. 350 OBJ files with the corresponding texture maps. So those are different meshes (mesh sequence) but belong to the same object. The Stop Motion OBJ plugin I mentioned enables loading them into Blender.

Comment: Sorry, can't share the blend file, it is huge (over 500MB) because of the imported mesh sequence.

Comment: Makes sense. Anyway, if it's just one object during the entire animation, you could add an empty, place it to where you want the camera to look, parent it to the object and make it the target of your camera instead of the object.

Comment: Great, that is a practical solution and it works for me. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad I helped.

Comment: You can create a Vertexgroup from the object and use this as target. Maybe this helps.